# What happens when extract() is used in an array with default key values (0,1,2,...)

Tags: php

I haven't given this much thought before but recently tried an sample code to c what happens when using extract() on an array with default key values, how is it supposed to work there.

```
    $testArray = array("apple", "ant", "book", "bag");
    extract($testArray);

    print_r($testArray);

    echo "${1}";
```

where will be the values apple, ant, book, and bag stored after extract() is applied.

This is a simple question but somebody please help me solve it.

Comment: rtm: [*... Checks each key to see whether it has a valid variable name. ...*](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.extract.php).

Comment: I know that using EXTR_PREFIX_ALL can solve the problem when the values will be stored with prefix attached to the numbers.

Comment: Thanks @Yoshi doubt cleared

Comment: That's a non-problem. Pure numerical keys, without prefix, will simply not be extracted. Not much to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is in your code it would not create any variables because there are not defined keys so the keys are 0, 1, 2... therefore, invalid variable names that will prevent them from being extracted.

if you use EXTR_PREFIX_ALL or EXTR_PREFIX_INVALID to prefix your keys with something to make them valid variable names then you could see them in

```
echo $whateveryourprefixis0; 
echo $whateveryourprefixis1; 
echo $whateveryourprefixis2; 
...
```

Comment: I think, that's the wrong distinction to make. Invalid keys, either implicit or explicit will not be extracted, if not otherwise configured. Simply ask yourself, would this key be a valid variable name. Don't think about where it comes from.

Comment: You are thinking where they came from not me... I said the keys ar 0, 1, 2... therefore invalid names...
The fact that they are 0, 1, 2 because they are numeric keys were just to explain why in this specific case the variables wouldn't be extracted

Comment: My point is, it's irrelevant whether the keys are *undefined* (e.g. not explicitely set), because even if they were, the validity-check would check them. That includes, even deliberately, *hand-crafted* arrays with numerical keys. E.g. `$x = [1=>2]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass no flag; **nothing**. With no flags, extract will only work if an associative array is passed.

From the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

> You must use an associative array; a numerically indexed array will not produce results unless you use **EXTR_PREFIX_ALL** or **EXTR_PREFIX_INVALID**.

So you *can* pass a numerical array, but you must pass a flag and a prefix for the variable name. Prefixes will be prepended to the invalid variable name, along with an underscore:

```
$pref = 'P';

$testArray = array("apple", "ant", "book", "bag");

extract($testArray, EXTR_PREFIX_INVALID, $pref);

var_dump($P_1); // ant
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/440224)